# Recover files from apk Google Play

Tags: android, apk, recovery

Some time ago i uploaded to google play an app for my family restaurant which was something like showing the menu, timetable, prices..all that stuff. It's still in the google play and i have access to it by google developers but the problem is that i lost all the code.

Is there any way of recovering the data to add some new info and then update my app?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Unless you have a backup copy of your release key, you will not be able to update your app in Google Play.  You will have to re-release it with a different package name.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a rooted device for this:

Install the app to your device, and then take the apk off of the device using:

1. Plug your “Rooted” Android device into your computer via the included USB cable.
2. From your adb command line (usually `C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\`) type `adb shell` and press enter
3. Switch to root user, type `su` and press enter
4. type “cd data/app“ and press enter
5. List all the installed apk files, type `ls` and press enter (find the one you want to extract)
6. In another command window, pull one of the files on to your computer by typing:
   `adb pull /data/app/application.apk name.apk` and press enter

Once you have the apk, rename it to `whatever.zip` and extract it as a zip file. You will now see a bunch of folders. Anything in your assets folder can be recovered now right away. For the java code, you must use [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) to convert `classes.dex` to a `.jar` file. After that, you can use [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to read the code from the .jar file.

To extract AndroidManifest.xml and everything in res folder(layout xml files, images etc.) you must use [APKTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)
Run the following command :

```
apktool.bat d sampleApp.apk
```

It also extracts the .smali file of all .class files, but these are difficult to read, and you should use the code from dex2jar instead.

Comment: @iagreen I went and checked that but I can't seem to find the option to download apks.

Comment: You are right, I thought it used to be there.  My mistake. 
Deleted the misinformation!

Comment: I have the app installed but i cant find it when doing ls :S

Comment: It may not be the name of your app. Look for your package name instead

Comment: None of them...so strange! I think i found the issue. In the google developers page it was set to be protected against copies. I've changed that. Let's see...

Answer (score 1):

If you Obfusticate your code using progaurd while generating the APK file, then its not possible.

If not, you can decompile the classes some extent and making some changes to the decompiled class and you can get it working... There are few tools to decompile the APJK file

Thanks,

Comment: Even if it is obfuscated, he will be able to work out most of the logic etc. from looking at it. after all, he wrote the original code.

Comment: Yeah, the code is very very simple but it took me a long time...that's why i'm trying this instead of re-doing it. Thank you all, mates!